# exporting R ggplot2 plots to LaTex

Tags: r

I usually export ggplot2 plots from R using "Save As" PDF and works fine, then I use `\includegraphics` from LaTex to include the fig. The problem is that it seems that the amount of data in these exported PDF from R are big e.g. over 600K each. If I export several PDF documents like this, the end PDF is super laggy to open.

My question is: how can I change either R or load differently from LaTex so that the end document is not so big while the quality of the plots is still very high?

Comment: Have you tried with Sweave or knitr? I do not know if this solves this specific problem with ggplot2 plots, but I find effortless integrate R ouputs in latex that export every plot. I have made in this way documents with dozens of different R plots without problems.

Comment: Is it the complexity of your plots? Make a scatter plot of 10 points in ggplot, save as PDF, and tell us if that is huge. If you are plotting a million points on a ggplot, yes, the PDF will be large. And don't just say 'massive', we talk kilobytes and megabytes here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it gets to the point where a PDF is bigger than a PNG at a high resolution for your end use, then make a high-resolution PNG file. For example, for a figure that will be 4 inches square on a page for print, you want 300dpi x 4 = 1200 pixels. So do:

```
png(file="plot1.png",width=1200,height=1200)
makemyplot()
dev.off() # close the png file
```

The cutoff point for this will vary on how much the PNG compression algorithm can do and how much overlapping "ink" you've got - all the ink in a PDF takes space, but you can do a million points to a PNG at the same location and it will only be a few bytes.

There are also assorted PDF compression tools, but I'm guessing you're on Windows and I use Unix command-line tools. While I'm on about command line tools, you can probably convert existing PDFs to raster PNGs with the 'convert' tool from the ImageMagick suite.

But 600k isn't *that* big. I'm working on a book with 2 megabyte PDFs on almost every page.